# WordPress not adding files properly to Media Library

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm busy making my own theme in WordPress. I am using a handler to add media files to WordPress library. It is located in functions.php and looks like this:

```
function handle_logo_upload() 
{
    if ( !function_exists( 'wp_handle_upload' ) ) {
        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
    }
        $uploadedfile = $_FILES['file'];
        $upload_overrides = array( 'test_form' => false );
        $movefile = wp_handle_upload( $uploadedfile, $upload_overrides );
        if ( $movefile ) {
            $wp_filetype = $movefile['type'];
            $filename = $movefile['file'];
            $wp_upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
            $attachment = array(
                'guid' => $wp_upload_dir['url'] . '/' . basename( $filename ),
                'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype,
                'post_title' => preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename($filename)),
                'post_content' => '',
                'post_status' => 'inherit'
            );
            $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $filename);
            echo '<br>';
            //return $attach_id;
            var_dump($uploadedfile);
            //wp_die('end');
        }

    return 'fail';      
}
```

At the bottom of this code, you can see `var_dump($uploadedfile);` This is returning NULL.

Also, when I upload an image using the theme function, i get a file looking like this in the media library: http://pasteboard.co/wgpYJRq.png

What the first thing that comes to mind?

Comment: You may want to post your question in the WordPress Development board, instead of SO. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: There's hardly anyone on that board that's why I posted here to try and get an answer.